# Every nonzero commutative ring contains a maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

[Proof](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/zorn1.pdf). Let S be the set of proper ideals in a commutative ring $R\neq 0$. Since the zero ideal
$(0)$ is a proper ideal, $S\neq ∅$. We partially order $S$ by inclusion.

**My question is**. Actually, is there a typo? Should we say that $R\backslash \left\{ 0\right\}$? I.e., not $R\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

No typo. The condition $R \neq 0$ is meant to exclude the triviality where $R$ is the ring consisting of a single element (thus $(0)$ fails to be proper). If you considered $R-\{0\}$ you would not have a ring (assuming $0$ is the additive identity).

Comment: Writer say $R\neq 0$ because $0$ is a zero ring, right?

Comment: Correct. $0$ is the ring with a single element. You can easily convince yourself this element must be its additive (and multiplicative) identity.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it should indeed be written "$R\ne\{0\}$". However, you will often find in algebra (and especially in notes) the symbol "$0$" used to indicate the eventual zero ring, the zero ideal, the zero $R$-module, the zero $\Bbb K$-vector space, the zero abelian group... It is not quite a typo, but rather a harmless and mostly unnoticed abuse of notation.

Answer (score 0):

It is $R\neq 0$ which implies that $S$ is not empty, since in this case $0$ is a proper ideal since it is different of $R$.